How to Select a value in Oracle SQL after a specific string
I have a column with data like below. the sequence of info can differ.
i need to extract the values for specific info and store in a different table.
can anyone please help me to provide the query/suggestions.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I Tried substr, Instr but not getting the desired results.

Please replace images with formatted text.

Unless you're on a really old version of Oracle you can use built-in JSON handling to do most of the work. The JSON_TABLE function has been around since 12cR1.

Here's an example of how to get element
SQL> with t as
  2  ( select treat('{"Values":{"ext::Name":"Scott", "ext::Age":"33"}}' as json) c from dual )
  3  select x.name, x.age
  4  from t t,
  5      json_table(c,'$.Values'
  6        columns (
  7          name varchar2(20)  path "ext::Name",
  8          age number path "ext::Age"
  9          )) x;

NAME                        AGE
-------------------- ----------
Scott                        33


Use JSON_TABLE() function to format and extraxt data from your column with json formated string:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ID, COL) AS
        ( Select 1, '{"Values":{"ext::Name":"Scott","ext::Age":"33","ext::DOB":"1989-02-19T13:42:00"}}' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, '{"Values":{"ext::Name":"Adam","ext::DOB":"1992-05-19T13:42:00"}}' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, '{"Values":{"ext::Name":"Tom","ext::DOB":"1985-07-19T13:42:00","ext::Age":"39"}}' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, '{"Values":{"ext::DOB":"1988-02-19T13:42:00","ext::Age":"34"}}' From Dual 
        )

--    S Q L :
Select  t.ID, j.Name, j.Age, j.DOB
From    tbl t,
              JSON_TABLE(COL,'$.Values'
                            columns ( Name VarChar2(32)   path "ext::Name",
                                      Age  Number(3)      path "ext::Age",
                                      DOB  DATE           path "ext::DOB"
                                    )
                        ) j;

/*    R e s u l t :  
        ID NAME                                    AGE DOB     
---------- -------------------------------- ---------- --------
         1 Scott                                    33 19.02.89
         2 Adam                                        19.05.92
         3 Tom                                      39 19.07.85
         4                                          34 19.02.88   */

